# Why is numpy.abs so much slower on complex64 than complex128 under windows 32-bit?

Tags: python, numpy

On my 32-bit Windows Vista machine I notice a significant (5x) slowdown when taking the absolute values of a fairly large `numpy.complex64` array when compared to a `numpy.complex128` array.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.random.randn(256,2048) + 1j*numpy.random.randn(256,2048)
>>> b = numpy.complex64(a)
>>> timeit c = numpy.float32(numpy.abs(a))
10 loops, best of 3: 27.5 ms per loop
>>> timeit c = numpy.abs(b)
1 loops, best of 3: 143 ms per loop
```

Obviously, the outputs in both cases are the same (to operating precision).

I do not notice the same effect on my Ubuntu 64-bit machine.

Is there a rational explanation for this?

Is this something that is common to all windows?

Comment: On my Win7 32-bit, they are about the same (~76ms).

Comment: I think the problem is that you are not getting statistically significant results from timeit - you have only done 10 and 1 loops respectively. If you manually specify a higher number such as 100 or 1000 with the -n switch, you should get more consistent results. But still, things like garbage collection of these arrays can cause variation between runs.

Comment: Using any -n unfortunately gives the same result. I've submitted it as a bug.